# Drupal 7 hook_node_view add a form to the content of a node

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

```
function example_module_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode)
{   
    $f =  drupal_get_form('example_module_form', $node);
    $node->content['data_collection_form'] = array('#value' => $f, '#weight' => 1); 
}
```

Why doesn't the form display? Am I doing something wrong? The form object is  being populated. I can do #markup => 'Something' and it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The return from `drupal_get_form` is actually a render array itself so you could just do this:

```
$f = drupal_get_form('example_module_form', $node);
$f['#weight'] = 1;
$node->content['data_collection_form'] = $f;
```

If you do want to do it the other way though the form should be a renderable 'element', so the key shouldn't be prefixed by `#`:

```
$f = drupal_get_form('example_module_form', $node);
$node->content['data_collection_form'] = array(0 => $f, '#weight' => 1);
```

All entries in a render array with a key prefixed with `#` are considered properties, while those that aren't are considered 'children' and are recursively rendered.

Answer (score 5):

Clive answer doesn't work in my case. I needed to call drupal_render and pass it as markup.

```
$form = drupal_get_form('example_module_form', $node);
$node->content['data_collection_form'] = array(
  '#markup' => drupal_render($form),
  '#weight' => 10,
);
```

This work, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way.

Comment: Your way and Clive's way worked both for me.  What also is strange that in looking at the official drupal_get_form API, the only parameter officially listed is just 1 ($form_id), but in various examples I see people using 2 parameters for drupal_get_form.  I am able to follow the official drupal_get_form API and use only one parameter and got everything working.  So in this example, I was able to just do: $form = drupal_get_form('example_module_form').

Comment: drupal_render form worked for me. My problem was that the word 'Array' was printed instead of the content of the form.