# How to add button to user profile page in drupal

Tags: php, button, drupal, view, user-profile

I start using drupal(7) 3 days ago and I have small task :

I'm using Profile2 Module to create 2 type of users (candite/employer) and I Want to create a button in the wiew page of the profile of employer.

[image]

I create new module for that to test if is an employer profil :

```
function ab_candidate_app_profile2_view_alter($build) {

  $test = $build['field_company_name']['#object'];
  if(isset($build))
    if($test->type == 'employer_'){

    // add the button here
    }


}
```

Thank you for your help

EDIT : and whene i do var_dump($build) i get next result :

```
array (size=12)
  '#view_mode' => string 'account' (length=7)
  'field_company_name' => 
    array (size=16)
      '#theme' => string 'field' (length=5)
      '#weight' => int 0
      '#title' => string 'Name' (length=4)
      '#access' => boolean true
      '#label_display' => string 'above' (length=5)
      '#view_mode' => string 'account' (length=7)
      '#language' => string 'und' (length=3)
      '#field_name' => string 'field_company_name' (length=18)
      '#field_type' => string 'text' (length=4)
      '#field_translatable' => string '0' (length=1)
      '#entity_type' => string 'profile2' (length=8)
      '#bundle' => string 'employer_' (length=9)
      '#object' => 
        object(Profile)[56]
          public 'pid' => string '6' (length=1)
          public 'type' => string 'employer_' (length=9)
          public 'label' => string 'Employer ' (length=9)
          public 'uid' => string '10' (length=2)
          public 'created' => string '1411278976' (length=10)
          public 'changed' => string '1411278976' (length=10)
          protected 'entityType' => string 'profile2' (length=8)
          protected 'entityInfo' => 
            array (size=22)
              ...
          protected 'idKey' => string 'pid' (length=3)
          protected 'nameKey' => string 'pid' (length=3)
          protected 'statusKey' => string 'status' (length=6)
          protected 'defaultLabel' => boolean false
          public 'field_company_name' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_logo' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_company_description' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_country' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'rdf_mapping' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'entity_view_prepared' => boolean true
      '#items' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
      '#formatter' => string 'text_default' (length=12)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          '#markup' => string 'adel' (length=4)
  'field_logo' => 
    array (size=16)
      '#theme' => string 'field' (length=5)
      '#weight' => int 2
      '#title' => string 'Logo' (length=4)
      '#access' => boolean true
      '#label_display' => string 'above' (length=5)
      '#view_mode' => string 'account' (length=7)
      '#language' => string 'und' (length=3)
      '#field_name' => string 'field_logo' (length=10)
      '#field_type' => string 'image' (length=5)
      '#field_translatable' => string '0' (length=1)
      '#entity_type' => string 'profile2' (length=8)
      '#bundle' => string 'employer_' (length=9)
      '#object' => 
        object(Profile)[56]
          public 'pid' => string '6' (length=1)
          public 'type' => string 'employer_' (length=9)
          public 'label' => string 'Employer ' (length=9)
          public 'uid' => string '10' (length=2)
          public 'created' => string '1411278976' (length=10)
          public 'changed' => string '1411278976' (length=10)
          protected 'entityType' => string 'profile2' (length=8)
          protected 'entityInfo' => 
            array (size=22)
              ...
          protected 'idKey' => string 'pid' (length=3)
          protected 'nameKey' => string 'pid' (length=3)
          protected 'statusKey' => string 'status' (length=6)
          protected 'defaultLabel' => boolean false
          public 'field_company_name' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_logo' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_company_description' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_country' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'rdf_mapping' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'entity_view_prepared' => boolean true
      '#items' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=13)
              ...
      '#formatter' => string 'image' (length=5)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          '#theme' => string 'image_formatter' (length=15)
          '#item' => 
            array (size=13)
              ...
          '#image_style' => string '' (length=0)
          '#path' => string '' (length=0)
  'field_company_description' => 
    array (size=16)
      '#theme' => string 'field' (length=5)
      '#weight' => int 3
      '#title' => string 'Description' (length=11)
      '#access' => boolean true
      '#label_display' => string 'above' (length=5)
      '#view_mode' => string 'account' (length=7)
      '#language' => string 'und' (length=3)
      '#field_name' => string 'field_company_description' (length=25)
      '#field_type' => string 'text_long' (length=9)
      '#field_translatable' => string '0' (length=1)
      '#entity_type' => string 'profile2' (length=8)
      '#bundle' => string 'employer_' (length=9)
      '#object' => 
        object(Profile)[56]
          public 'pid' => string '6' (length=1)
          public 'type' => string 'employer_' (length=9)
          public 'label' => string 'Employer ' (length=9)
          public 'uid' => string '10' (length=2)
          public 'created' => string '1411278976' (length=10)
          public 'changed' => string '1411278976' (length=10)
          protected 'entityType' => string 'profile2' (length=8)
          protected 'entityInfo' => 
            array (size=22)
              ...
          protected 'idKey' => string 'pid' (length=3)
          protected 'nameKey' => string 'pid' (length=3)
          protected 'statusKey' => string 'status' (length=6)
          protected 'defaultLabel' => boolean false
          public 'field_company_name' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_logo' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_company_description' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_country' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'rdf_mapping' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'entity_view_prepared' => boolean true
      '#items' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
      '#formatter' => string 'text_default' (length=12)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          '#markup' => string 'teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest' (length=23)
  'field_country' => 
    array (size=16)
      '#theme' => string 'field' (length=5)
      '#weight' => int 4
      '#title' => string 'Country' (length=7)
      '#access' => boolean true
      '#label_display' => string 'above' (length=5)
      '#view_mode' => string 'account' (length=7)
      '#language' => string 'und' (length=3)
      '#field_name' => string 'field_country' (length=13)
      '#field_type' => string 'list_text' (length=9)
      '#field_translatable' => string '0' (length=1)
      '#entity_type' => string 'profile2' (length=8)
      '#bundle' => string 'employer_' (length=9)
      '#object' => 
        object(Profile)[56]
          public 'pid' => string '6' (length=1)
          public 'type' => string 'employer_' (length=9)
          public 'label' => string 'Employer ' (length=9)
          public 'uid' => string '10' (length=2)
          public 'created' => string '1411278976' (length=10)
          public 'changed' => string '1411278976' (length=10)
          protected 'entityType' => string 'profile2' (length=8)
          protected 'entityInfo' => 
            array (size=22)
              ...
          protected 'idKey' => string 'pid' (length=3)
          protected 'nameKey' => string 'pid' (length=3)
          protected 'statusKey' => string 'status' (length=6)
          protected 'defaultLabel' => boolean false
          public 'field_company_name' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_logo' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_company_description' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'field_country' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'rdf_mapping' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'entity_view_prepared' => boolean true
      '#items' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      '#formatter' => string 'list_default' (length=12)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          '#markup' => string 'Malaysia (MY)' (length=13)
  '#pre_render' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '_field_extra_fields_pre_render' (length=30)
  '#entity_type' => string 'profile2' (length=8)
  '#bundle' => string 'employer_' (length=9)
  '#theme' => string 'entity' (length=6)
  '#entity' => 
    object(Profile)[56]
      public 'pid' => string '6' (length=1)
      public 'type' => string 'employer_' (length=9)
      public 'label' => string 'Employer ' (length=9)
      public 'uid' => string '10' (length=2)
      public 'created' => string '1411278976' (length=10)
      public 'changed' => string '1411278976' (length=10)
      protected 'entityType' => string 'profile2' (length=8)
      protected 'entityInfo' => 
        array (size=22)
          'label' => string 'Profile' (length=7)
          'plural label' => string 'Profiles' (length=8)
          'description' => string 'Profile2 user profiles.' (length=23)
          'entity class' => string 'Profile' (length=7)
          'controller class' => string 'EntityAPIController' (length=19)
          'base table' => string 'profile' (length=7)
          'fieldable' => boolean true
          'view modes' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'entity keys' => 
            array (size=4)
              ...
          'bundles' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          'bundle keys' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'label callback' => string 'entity_class_label' (length=18)
          'uri callback' => string 'entity_class_uri' (length=16)
          'access callback' => string 'profile2_access' (length=15)
          'module' => string 'profile2' (length=8)
          'metadata controller class' => string 'Profile2MetadataController' (length=26)
          'static cache' => boolean true
          'field cache' => boolean true
          'load hook' => string 'profile2_load' (length=13)
          'translation' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'schema_fields_sql' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'configuration' => boolean false
      protected 'idKey' => string 'pid' (length=3)
      protected 'nameKey' => string 'pid' (length=3)
      protected 'statusKey' => string 'status' (length=6)
      protected 'defaultLabel' => boolean false
      public 'field_company_name' => 
        array (size=1)
          'und' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      public 'field_logo' => 
        array (size=1)
          'und' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      public 'field_company_description' => 
        array (size=1)
          'und' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      public 'field_country' => 
        array (size=1)
          'und' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      public 'rdf_mapping' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'entity_view_prepared' => boolean true
  '#language' => string 'en' (length=2)
  '#page' => null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it by overrieding the user-profile.tpl.php with this code :

```
<?php print render($user_profile); 

  if(isset($user_profile['profile_employer_'])){
  $account_info=menu_get_object('user');
  $acount_id = $account_info->uid;

 // var_dump($account_info);die();

  echo '<a href="/jobPortal/Apply/'.$acount_id.'">Apply Now</a>';
  }
  ?>
```

I overied this file in the next path :

C:\wamp\www\jobPortal\themes\bartik\templates\

Comment: Glad you found a solution. However, I really suggest to keep tpls clean from any php code processing. I have faced enough performance problems with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you need to add a button on profile display and not specifically a "view" from Views module. In that case you must use 
[hook_node_view](https://api.drupal.org/hook_node_view)

Here is an example
https://www.drupal.org/node/1993368#comment-7406538

or a check out more elaborative answer at 
[Drupal 7 hook_node_view add a form to the content of a node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892141/drupal-7-hook-node-view-add-a-form-to-the-content-of-a-node). You can add a button in the form and call on display.

In case you are using a view from "Views" module, I would suggest to better create a block in your code and place on the particular page rather than altering views. Altered views can be really difficult to maintain. It is best to keep them only for displaying DB content and not embedding forms.

Still you might like to go through the comments on this thread regarding a similar query https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/91186/how-do-i-embed-a-node-creation-form-inside-a-view